# How do I pass a variable from a try to an action event?

Tags: java, javafx

```
try(FileInputStream fis = (new FileInputStream("*FILE*"))){
            Player player = new Player(fis);
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.setText("Start");
            Button btn2 = new Button();
            btn2.setText("Stop");
        }catch(JavaLayerException | IOException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        this.player = player;
        try{
            new playMusic(player).start();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event)->{
        player.close();
    });
```

- It feels like this should be something really simple but I couldn't find anything anywhere

Comment: Why not putting everything in one try catch ? or maybe use the file try catch alone, then test if file isn't null (after the try catch for the file) and then do all the buttons things

Comment: thanks, that seemed to fix it but now i get loads of errors when I click the button. I ran the same code just without the buttons and just as a block of code and it ran fine but I get errors like java.io.FileInputStream.available(Native Method) and then loads of javazoom errors

Comment: (So the problem is retaining the **unreleased** resource even after returning control to the event loop.) (Leaving aside what happens if you play the music twice.)

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you mean.  Not done masses of coding and just starting A levels.  Only really done basic python and a bit of java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you move the code accessing the variable inside the `try` block or you declare the variable outside of the `try` block and make sure it's initialized when the event handler is registered.

```
final Player player;
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("*FILE*")){
    player = new Player(fis);
} catch(JavaLayerException | IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();

    // prevent access to uninitialized player variable by exiting the method
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("Start");
Button btn2 = new Button();
btn2.setText("Stop");

btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    this.player = player;
    try{
        new playMusic(player).start();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});

btn2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event)->{
    player.close();
});
```

Instead of

```
throw new RuntimeException(e);
```

you could also exit the method gracefully using

```
return;
```

instead.

---

#### Edit

If `Player` is not reading all the code in the constructor, you must not close it. try-with-resources does this though. Change to a `try` `catch`

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("*FILE*");
    try {
        player = new Player(fis);
    } catch(JavaLayerException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fis.close(); // close stream on player creation failure

        // prevent access to uninitialized player variable by exiting the method
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
} catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();

    // prevent access to uninitialized player variable by exiting the method
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the file needs to be kept open even after execution has returned to the event loop.

Comment: this solved my first problem but then created errors with javazoom and FileInputStream

Comment: Probably you're required to leave the stream you pass to `Player`'s constructor open. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much :) this worked but I'm not entirely sure why this did and the last didn't though?  Apologies if this is frustratingly simple and I should just understand.

Comment: @OwenCook Just consider something simpler than `Player` that also reads the `InputStream` passed to it when calling it's methods later: `Scanner`. If you create a scanner using `new Scanner(fis)` and close `fis`, no more data can be read from the stream and calling `Scanner.nextLine()` fails. try-with-resources automatically calls the `close` method(s) of it's resources after exiting the scope of the try block which is why the `Player` instance is not able to access the stream in the event handlers.

Comment: ah okay this makes a lot more sense.  vielen dank